# Listing all subdirectories with a specified name

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, command-prompt, cmd

I am trying to get a list of paths of all subdirectories (recursively) which have some specified name, e.g. `"bin"`. The problem is that if current directory contains subdirectory of that name, DIR command will be executed only within that subdirectory, ignoring other subdirectories.

Example:

```
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH>dir *bin* /ad /s /b
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\bin
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\Apache\2bin
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\Apache\bin
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\Apache\bin1
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\C#\ConsoleApps\MiscTests\bin

C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH>dir bin* /ad /s /b
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\bin
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\Apache\bin
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\Apache\bin1
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\C#\ConsoleApps\MiscTests\bin

C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH>dir bin /ad /s /b
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\bin\test    

C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH>rmdir bin /s /q

C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH>dir bin /ad /s /b
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\Apache\bin
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\C#\ConsoleApps\MiscTests\bin

C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH>
```

`dir *bin* /ad /s /b` outputs all subdirectories that have `bin` in their name. And this output is ok. Same with `dir bin* /ad /s /b` which outputs all subdirectories which name begins with `bin`. But `dir bin /ad /s /b` outputs only the content of the first child of the current directory which has name `bin`. Desired output is:

```
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\bin
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\Apache\bin
C:\DEVELOPMENT\RESEARCH\C#\ConsoleApps\MiscTests\bin
```

How can I achieve this?

NOTE: If current directory does not contain `bin` child, output is as expected. (I deleted `bin` child to show this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your current directory contains a `bin` subdirectory, then it is difficult using standard DOS commands. I think you have three basic options:

```
# Option 1: FOR and check directory existance (modified from MBu's answer - the
# original answer just appended 'bin' to all directories whether it existed or not)
# (replace the 'echo %A' with your desired action)
for /r /d %A in (bin) do if exist %A\NUL echo %A

# Option 2: PowerShell (second item is if you need to verify it is a directory)
Get-ChildItem -filter bin -recurse
Get-ChildItem -filter bin -recurse |? { $_.Attributes -match 'Directory' }

# Option 3: Use UNIX/Cygwin find.exe (not to be confused in DOS find)
# (you can locate on the net, such as GNU Utilities for Win32)
find.exe . -name bin
find.exe . -name bin -type d
```

- [DOS Testing if drive or directory exists](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65994)
- [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
- [GNU Utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Option 1 does the job. I am actually writing a short script that deletes subdirectories with a given name. I combined your answer (so will accept it) with some other commands and got what I wanted. Many thanks!

Comment: option 1 - doesn't work in Vista with NUL. Keep the \ but remove NUL and it works in Vista. Also, should use quotes. if exist "%A\"

Comment: @dbenham Good point on the quotes. I am surprised about NUL not working on Vista though. I tested on Win7 and Win2008 and it worked, and the article (DOS Testing if drive...) refers to Win 3.11 so I would have expected it to work for just about everything.

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried the NUL at work on Vista and it worked fine. But I swear I tried it on my Vista 64 at home and it failed. I'll double check when I get back home. I know checking for existence of `folder\nul` was a standard technique back in MS-DOS. But I remember learning that Windows introduced some complication that makes it unreliable in certain circumstances - I just can't remember the details.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
for /R /D %A in (*bin*) do echo %A
```